# Maintaining both on-line (Azure) and off-line version of a website

Tags: c#, database, azure, ef-code-first, code-first

*Note: Not sure if the question is asked the right way. This is how I perceive the issue but it's fully possible that the problem is addressable form a totally different angle, which I'm unaware of due to the ignorance.*

**Question**
Is there a built-in database available for an out-of-the-box, MVC solution? If so, how do I find out its connection string?

Current string is for Azure and looks like this (frankly, it scares living excrement out me because I don't understand most of it).

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="
  Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;
  Initial Catalog=aspnet-Plong-20141107210818;
  Integrated Security=SSPI;
  AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Plong-20141107210818.mdf" 
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**Background info**
I'm developing a site and publish it to the Azure. It has some connections to the database and I'm using Code First and Entity Framework. Everything works great (maybe except the fact that it takes a few seconds to upload and initialize the page prior showing, which is annoying if I've only made changes to the markup of Razor).

In fact, all's been set up pretty much automagically, and I didn't have to configure much at all. Now, it's biting my in the sitting device because of the following.

I need to be able to run my site on the local host (using <kbd>F5</kbd>, if you will) because I'll be going off-line (or at the very least under a very lousy connection). I can do that right now, except for the page that contacts the database reference, where I'm getting the error below.

I get what the problem is - no local DB set up using code first. I wonder if there's a lazy man's solution to it (using some built in DB and code-first-able). If so, where do I set it up? I prefer to keep the reference to default connection string as intact as possible but if I need to edit it (or, most likely, add a new one and reference it), how do I learn the correct connection string?! (Yes, I know, this is the price I pay for taking an easy way out letting Azure configure everything for me. Head down in shame.)

> {"Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations."}

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know that's not a connection string to SQL Azure, but for a local (development) database. It will create a .mdf file in your App_Data folder. You can find connection strings to SQL Azure somewhere in the Azure dashboard. I switch between dev en production using for example:

```
    public MyContext : DbContext
    {
      public MyContext()
#if DEBUG
          : base("development")
#else
          : base("production")
#endif
      {
      }
    }
```

However, you could also use XML transformation of the `web.config`, `web.debug.config` and `web.release.config`. Note that `web.debug.config` is not really used when you run your application locally, so put your development connection strings in `web.config` and publish your application in release mode so the XML transformation of `web.release.config` takes place.

**Edit: Get the SQL Azure connection string**

Got to the management portal and click on SQL Databases. Click on the database and go to Dashboard. On the right side you see "Show connection strings". It looks something like this:

```
Server=tcp:xxx.database.windows.net,1433;Database={your_db_name};User ID={your_user_id};Password={your_password_here};Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;
```

Comment: Actually, I got the connection string from the Azure portal. That's why I assumed it was "azury". Maybe it's like that because my site (uploaded to Azure) and the DB both reside on the same server in the cloud? How can I find out the connection string to the DB I have on Azure? (As I mentioned - the one displayed here I've got from there but maybe I looked in wrong place...)

Comment: @KonradViltersten I modified my answer with info about SQL Azure connection strings.